# iOS application failed to resume how to fix it?

Tags: iphone, ios4, crash-dumps

i have no idea to fix this issues , any idea?

```
Incident Identifier: 778B453C-111C-4575-919E-0C73BDD679B4
CrashReporter Key:   cc6fa311f4d178cd2a1c946ced641fab87e0181d
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         PantipCafe [792]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/DBFF211E-F7F2-439A-91FF-E118F476567A/PantipCafe.app/PantipCafe
Identifier:      PantipCafe
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-11-15 07:40:23.772 +0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.1 (8B117)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
PantipCafe failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 0.800 (user 0.310, system 0.490), 16% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32fd1c98 0x32fd1000 + 3224
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32fd3d64 0x32fd1000 + 11620
2   AppSupport                      0x3003509e 0x30025000 + 65694
3   AppSupport                      0x300343e4 0x30025000 + 62436
4   AppSupport                      0x30033d76 0x30025000 + 60790
5   AppSupport                      0x30032eba 0x30025000 + 57018
6   AppSupport                      0x3003308e 0x30025000 + 57486
7   iAd                             0x346dfbcc 0x346cd000 + 76748
8   iAd                             0x346e0e46 0x346cd000 + 81478
9   iAd                             0x346d4aa2 0x346cd000 + 31394
10  iAd                             0x346d40bc 0x346cd000 + 28860
11  iAd                             0x346e0114 0x346cd000 + 78100
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3445642c 0x3440b000 + 308268
13  CoreFoundation                  0x344562fe 0x3440b000 + 307966
14  iAd                             0x346e549a 0x346cd000 + 99482
15  CoreFoundation                  0x34454216 0x3440b000 + 299542
16  CoreFoundation                  0x34453f88 0x3440b000 + 298888
17  iAd                             0x346e4a92 0x346cd000 + 96914
18  iAd                             0x346e4f4a 0x346cd000 + 98122
19  CoreFoundation                  0x3446b9ce 0x3440b000 + 395726
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3443fcdc 0x3440b000 + 216284
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3443fca0 0x3440b000 + 216224
22  CoreFoundation                  0x34432566 0x3440b000 + 161126
23  CoreFoundation                  0x34432270 0x3440b000 + 160368
24  CoreFoundation                  0x34432178 0x3440b000 + 160120
25  GraphicsServices                0x3026b5ec 0x30267000 + 17900
26  GraphicsServices                0x3026b698 0x30267000 + 18072
27  UIKit                           0x31ad011c 0x31acc000 + 16668
28  UIKit                           0x31ace128 0x31acc000 + 8488
29  PantipCafe                      0x00002144 0x1000 + 4420
30  PantipCafe                      0x000020e0 0x1000 + 4320

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32ffe330 0x32fd1000 + 185136
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x330a7b6c 0x32fd1000 + 879468
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x330a75bc 0x32fd1000 + 878012
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x330a775c 0x32fd1000 + 878428
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3304b67a 0x32fd1000 + 501370
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33044190 0x32fd1000 + 471440

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32fd1c98 0x32fd1000 + 3224
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32fd3d64 0x32fd1000 + 11620
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34432c38 0x3440b000 + 162872
3   CoreFoundation                  0x344324c2 0x3440b000 + 160962
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34432270 0x3440b000 + 160368
5   CoreFoundation                  0x34432178 0x3440b000 + 160120
6   WebCore                         0x34b524e2 0x34b50000 + 9442
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3304b27e 0x32fd1000 + 500350
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x330402a8 0x32fd1000 + 455336

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32fd1c98 0x32fd1000 + 3224
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32fd3d64 0x32fd1000 + 11620
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34432c38 0x3440b000 + 162872
3   CoreFoundation                  0x344324c2 0x3440b000 + 160962
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34432270 0x3440b000 + 160368
5   CoreFoundation                  0x34432178 0x3440b000 + 160120
6   Foundation                      0x33276686 0x33249000 + 185990
7   Foundation                      0x33254222 0x33249000 + 45602
8   Foundation                      0x3324d2d6 0x33249000 + 17110
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3304b27e 0x32fd1000 + 500350
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x330402a8 0x32fd1000 + 455336

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32ff6060 0x32fd1000 + 151648
1   CoreFoundation                  0x34469dfc 0x3440b000 + 388604
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3304b27e 0x32fd1000 + 500350
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x330402a8 0x32fd1000 + 455336

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x5dfff +PantipCafe armv7  <60c8ab9995c52c7279a6bc28f8a0808c> /var/mobile/Applications/DBFF211E-F7F2-439A-91FF-E118F476567A/PantipCafe.app/PantipCafe
   0xc1000 -    0xc1fff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
   0xf1000 -    0xf2fff +MobileLoader.dylib armv6  /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileLoader.dylib
   0xf6000 -    0xf7fff  dns.so armv7  <240b8d3f07b4fcb234de598f8e67de1a> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv7  <a11905c8ef7906bf4b8910fc551f9dbb> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30025000 - 0x30055fff  AppSupport armv7  <20908678e860c23207574337097b94f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30056000 - 0x30063fff  OpenGLES armv7  <6bdd1b930c09cfec7c6c7629551c0cbd> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3006c000 - 0x3007ffff  libmis.dylib armv7  <e47fe2a55644ffd53fab6547ef59ffab> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x300a5000 - 0x301c0fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <6dcc299d5ca75f73afbc98a1b4bd2c7a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x301e2000 - 0x301effff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <98d9b7a105217af3d9bb744ccdf8d5dc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x301f5000 - 0x3021efff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <fe6ab911eb680b758f415e20afec8e00> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x30267000 - 0x30273fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <7075593b53fcd90c8d2aa40ba9ff4397> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3028a000 - 0x30323fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <3f29fbbfe5abb8969cda45e0efe42af5> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x30324000 - 0x30379fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <ec6199ca9490baba91f9bc644063bef1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3037a000 - 0x3043cfff  CFNetwork armv7  <0860d900e5328f349290feaaa3eb6e9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3044f000 - 0x3053bfff  MusicLibrary armv7  <6e60d6565924f03d819e330080fc0dfe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x30548000 - 0x30551fff  CoreVideo armv7  <d47b741a05fdbed287a454e834aeede2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3056c000 - 0x305b7fff  GMM armv7  <140d9a6633393f644c3aa852fe7e7e42> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x305d2000 - 0x305d4fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <ef3a36680985b4db12a778d62f37961f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3069b000 - 0x30744fff  QuartzCore armv7  <1628da07ea69b89c0b6a5a7d2dc42a24> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30778000 - 0x3077efff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <e89050debe57ae71a3f0ed2bc9c46145> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x307d9000 - 0x307e0fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0011bd5af0230fcaf63005f7eefa11dd> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x30885000 - 0x309b5fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <9420239a007f28f7aa2163b05053d110> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x309b6000 - 0x309b9fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0d33b320dcac6cb6a594171f3f8c3b04> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x309ba000 - 0x309c0fff  IAP armv7  <e0bde1a923179f4eaea83b8e8ca602d7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x309ca000 - 0x309e9fff  Bom armv7  <f49558f211241498f37af577051611b3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x309f2000 - 0x309f4fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8b23f794f02c2f7572a8fe6532630161> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x30bed000 - 0x30c05fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <6d9b86e946a18416f1a50586beabd716> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x30c06000 - 0x30c09fff  CertUI armv7  <4d350d880f67fad89bc143e7159c1ac0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x30c23000 - 0x30cc3fff  Celestial armv7  <aa0773c3d8e022e5a0b307b1db79232a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x30d3b000 - 0x30da9fff  AVFoundation armv7  <05feb4f546c261049ccc8d6a5ccf8790> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x30dfa000 - 0x30e99fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <28583b202a5108a6e93c9990a2f1d576> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x30e9a000 - 0x30ed4fff  IOKit armv7  <6810c1b44dd12227780dc88c76b692e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30f39000 - 0x30fcafff  AddressBookUI armv7  <99283bc397692fbf3c296b0c1a298aed> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x30fe6000 - 0x30febfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <dabd32c6bac583a6809c2b04c5907acf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x30ffd000 - 0x31030fff  CoreLocation armv7  <e4fb7d0e9675955039ed7a452c3dc935> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x310a7000 - 0x310e9fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <75ae0cfae42b263eb4de427a1b991f9a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x311f8000 - 0x3131efff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ed7b56f98da764e4639611ae6327417b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x31325000 - 0x31563fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <ef4a9b7fdccb3317b5b620ae59a70490> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x31564000 - 0x31565fff  CoreSurface armv7  <586f25579330ac060decd2df4cc05bd8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x31573000 - 0x31573fff  vecLib armv7  <e1d93756e63104d2861a277e8a70df44> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31574000 - 0x315a4fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <fbd7776498c593443b467d5dc31d2615> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x315b1000 - 0x315fcfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9e5eadf1538d47142a4257d2fa5bbdd5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31600000 - 0x31615fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <1ed920d5a995cd94e71c41631d7c551e> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x317d1000 - 0x318befff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <485fd1df5d59421108c9f006a1aca6c6> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x31a18000 - 0x31a43fff  DataAccess armv7  <7320fc47e54348166062dcfcc4c17439> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x31a44000 - 0x31a47fff  ArtworkCache armv7  <1f8c5b5641eba117423f385dda0dffa3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x31a5d000 - 0x31acbfff  ProofReader armv7  <184b846e1f602485068db7a9c943595f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x31acc000 - 0x32d0cfff  UIKit armv7  <3f1f8f7555dcf93cc4ce2146286bd3f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32da1000 - 0x32da9fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <e86dd3313cbef5a3a0fb8598f6b0ab18> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x32dc1000 - 0x32dd0fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <17fc35fddaa84a39ca7f260b9f220e4b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x32e3c000 - 0x32e48fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <b715ca60b9e99b3b2b4f8270c478c138> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x32e49000 - 0x32ef2fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <1d74fa3a5cec309857503a51cb2df667> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x32f3a000 - 0x32f90fff  EventKit armv7  <f560f34fe9f784df16c7451a7c3d5a76> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x32fd1000 - 0x330defff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0792bef82e8cde31cb32d06e80262288> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x330df000 - 0x330e7fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <6fb15d72d3ee5444d901dc9ef974a3b3> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33225000 - 0x33236fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <23a6206a542a6b02dd4c5103af3f9da2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x33237000 - 0x3323afff  ApplePushService armv7  <ee70c20a69f16dd4d43e4489903047bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x33249000 - 0x33368fff  Foundation armv7  <5cffb5458e87beccdb75770cea676753> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x333be000 - 0x33445fff  Message armv7  <0811df7f3cfa8b9c241cd3bdf06de209> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x337d2000 - 0x337d5fff  IOSurface armv7  <83927fd3641791e5bcdadcca0edd196b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x337d6000 - 0x337f5fff  MobileSync armv7  <3dfdf772f29393bcca4fa113b46cee52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x33821000 - 0x3384afff  ContentIndex armv7  <1b790132dfce754bee3775628f26c8eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3384b000 - 0x3394ffff  CoreData armv7  <36b5f42fcdceea61bedb2838f8279714> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x3395a000 - 0x33970fff  RawCamera armv7  <bef0590943338e945db7e7cbf274c624> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x33971000 - 0x33a31fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <49029949741e10f21b178b0a4b2df979> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x33a32000 - 0x33a3dfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <19a78978d5908bedc6496470fe542936> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x33a3e000 - 0x33a6dfff  CoreText armv7  <0855144a7f9eeade285f2e7c030f7478> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x33aa2000 - 0x33aabfff  ITSync armv7  <6de2eeb0276458257e6c972f7195a787> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x33aac000 - 0x33bcafff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <4949e62e1d8a0d2d5c341752744ebda0> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x33c6a000 - 0x33c98fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <41663f59614034ba151e9b4f86e1e141> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33c99000 - 0x33cd0fff  Security armv7  <4770002d4b443c186dc1e3ddaa1787c8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x33d9e000 - 0x33de8fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <7b2a8cf02f12c636c6db7f5e1906f9f0> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33de9000 - 0x33e23fff  CoreMedia armv7  <c85a11d97cb8820e325db898b0740f2e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33f1e000 - 0x33f60fff  MessageUI armv7  <f531fb1f0d3cc0922d643597f5ef23a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x33f8e000 - 0x33fa2fff  libJapaneseConverter.dylib armv7  <4a4706892c8667fba13f51eb3252fa72> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libJapaneseConverter.dylib
0x33fc0000 - 0x33fc3fff  ActorKit armv7  <bc4365d27ab1fcdf780d64c4d180e417> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x33fc6000 - 0x33fc7fff  DataMigration armv7  <c2889c5e6185ac7ef67fe4147344d410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x33fe6000 - 0x3401bfff  TextInput armv7  <140797a7e860df6f22831604ec08dd88> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x3401c000 - 0x34024fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <a19586adf6b24dabd61f3f56a350a042> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x34099000 - 0x340c8fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <b79a5a4f0506ce17bedeef7799e81687> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3426c000 - 0x3427afff  Notes armv7  <22108af89c58bf3bf01c7109915dad9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x3427e000 - 0x34325fff  WebKit armv7  <a8bfa45e5c19efcf95e184e658d61a18> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x34327000 - 0x34330fff  AccountSettings armv7  <aba19b26f9a5e950bd9861c93e265a3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34334000 - 0x34337fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <eb847a9560239a5cdd1f19fc6195ecb8> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3437b000 - 0x3438bfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <51e935a31a31072ec7a10b7b80adc85e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x3438c000 - 0x343ccfff  CoreAudio armv7  <96e6c0b793449c9e08a507693c956aad> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3440b000 - 0x344defff  CoreFoundation armv7  <adb562d8b5eaadbb874e255a09d0e04b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x344df000 - 0x34522fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <deafb4c98c723215e43f07c3bf6d77e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3452b000 - 0x34538fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <df1574298fea28ad799e1549425b44a4> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34557000 - 0x3455afff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <6c367af97f27bcdac9362897e0bae546> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x34609000 - 0x3460bfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <2b26c74e98505a26da656eeb781b16cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x34610000 - 0x34643fff  AddressBook armv7  <59286907142fc76ead3dab9fa3baff5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x346cd000 - 0x346f0fff  iAd armv7  <bb2ef32385f825542b79935a3dc2c98d> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x346f1000 - 0x34730fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <f261ea6e5f00e4ba4fda02bb4d7712b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34738000 - 0x34738fff  Accelerate armv7  <0601858b149ba0586210ad15b0d41c1e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x34751000 - 0x34757fff  WebUI armv7  <aa126505873f153b0fcf54da26d54095> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x34758000 - 0x3475afff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee5bb3b14b91bcf192f0d18e9f31c40a> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3475d000 - 0x349f7fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <795a79616d24a733fae53d9df6c46998> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34a05000 - 0x34a12fff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <e25d58c42913fda8f660726585b53f02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x34aa9000 - 0x34ab0fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <e8c579a3faa687bfb52ba68fbe7b17be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x34ab8000 - 0x34b49fff  ImageIO armv7  <3f421780e67f0219e416287d3e684b54> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34b4b000 - 0x34b4ffff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0c10a998f46151b69a9060b5879973cc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34b50000 - 0x350a2fff  WebCore armv7  <4d60fdc638b6218c26d3c143af5e829c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x350a5000 - 0x350aefff  WebBookmarks armv7  <527d15dc1e27c410c7474f306769a0a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x350c1000 - 0x35106fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <7de3ef8f02a0af58ef9f58348d5dbc50> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x35143000 - 0x3525cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <71ef015f1994cf85658df91a50a37815> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x35288000 - 0x352b6fff  MIME armv7  <0cbbaadc15780476e4fcdcdf14bbe4ba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x353d9000 - 0x3540cfff  iCalendar armv7  <4e036eca5114ea49caf2a80ca52e9d0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x35426000 - 0x35455fff  QuickLook armv7  <0e54a89bb297491e416dbc51a542fdd6> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x35456000 - 0x3546cfff  EAP8021X armv7  <419b97910c4b517f38697a3121775bc7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3546d000 - 0x35555fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <ef656cb58e56a36789ee17d4d925e9ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being terminated like this means your app is running afoul of the watchdog timer and blocking the main thread for too long before allowing the system to run its event loop. There are plenty of possible causes, but if it occurs consistently, take a look at what you're doing in the main thread that may be taking more than a few seconds at a time, decreasing your app's responsiveness.